# Cocoapods how to achieve multiple podfile?

Tags: ios, cocoapods

Cocoapods how to achieve multiple podfile?Multi-manipulation of podfiles in componentized projects can cause conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

Need a file to write these, do what you need pods and use terminal to run the file

```
target 'MyApp' do
    pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.6'
    pod 'ORStackView', '~> 3.0'
    pod 'SwiftyJSON', '~> 2.3'
end
```

And try to google the detail about how to use cocoapods may help you a lot.